# How to check my site speed?

Tags: web-server, performance, wordpress, web-hosting, page-speed

im the developer and in charge of a company's Wordpress based site
our site started to run a lot slower recently and i am trying to figure it out for two weeks now!

My main problem is that every online site speed test I found is so inconsistent: sometimes i get 1 second load time and sometimes i get 30 seconds .. I cant figure out the problem this way because i dont know if something i changed is responsible for the drop of speed because the speed check tool is inconsistent

I opened up a testing environment and trying to remove my plugins and theme to figure out what makes it slow.. but i find it really hard to tell..

Any Ideas at all?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to chat with your server administrators to figure out if it's server-related or your application.

Comment: [http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) Of course perform this from outside your Lan. It may give some clues, not the answer

Answer (score 2):

New Relic is your best friend in a situation like this. You could be having a API Call to a twitter plugin that's hanging you up, or low IOPS to a database server. New relic will save you hours from digging through logs.